# Discord.py Disconnecting voice client ends when I disconnet from a different server

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

When I disconnect my bot from a channel, it stops all music in other channels. I'm currently using the create_ytdl_player() function to stream music. Any help?

Current Code:

```
elif message.startswith('~disconnect'):
for x in client.voice_clients:
    if x.server == msg.server:
        print("Found Server!")
        await x.disconnect()
        VoiceOn[msg.channel.server.id] = False #A Dictionary which I use to detect if music is currently playing in the server.
        break
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [mcve] example and also check [ask] so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known Discord bug, there's nothing you can do about it.
https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/issues/477

(Re-launching the client should fix it, until the bot disconnects again).

The only real workaround here is to have a different account per voice session. It's not super elegant (and does not scale very well).